# Are there more advanced LUKS key schemes, e.g. 2 of 3 keys needed?

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

It seems like the two main LUKS encryption options are:

1. USB keyfile (see https://superuser.com/questions/149578/how-can-i-use-a-keyfile-on-a-removable-usb-drive-for-my-encrypted-root-in-debian)
2. Typing in a password

These both have weaknesses. The first can be overcome by stealing the USB drive. In the second case, a keylogger could be used, or I could be forced to give over the password.

Would it be possible to create an encryption scheme that required both of the options? Then, if I was given an injuction to provide the password, I could destroy the USB drive (e.g. burn it on the stovetop); conversely, if someone stole my USB drive, they would need to get my password as well.

It seems the existing LUKS key slot idea is that providing a key for *any* key slot will unlock the device, not that one has to provide a key for *all*, or say "2 of 3" key slots (iirc the latter can be accomplished in a cryptographically secure manner using a Galois field).

(Also, I happen to be on an OpenSuSE system, so please keep answers distro-agnostic or something that can work on SuSE.)

Comment: IANAL, but destroying the key after receiving a subpoena to produce it is likely to get you into serious trouble.

Comment: @cjm, that would be hard to prove, however. I could have "lost" it earlier.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think something like this exists right out of the box, but it should be possible. I'll put together some references for you.

First there's /etc/crypttab - typically you specify a key file or password in the third slot, but some distros allow you to specify an option in the fourth field called `keyscript` (debian and opensuse support this: http://linux.frank4dd.com/en/man5/crypttab.htm). This script (which must be in "/lib/cryptsetup/scripts" iirc) can use the third field (what would normally be just the keyfile or password) as an argument. The keyscript's job is to send the actual decryption key to stdout, which cryptsetup then uses as the luks key in the normal fashion.

Second is that you will likely need to write the keyscript. `netkeyscript` (in github) is an example of a keyscript that listens on a UDP multicast socket for the password; here is another more detailed example of a custom key script, complete with an implementation in `sh`: http://wejn.org/how-to-make-passwordless-cryptsetup.html. How you code the keyscript (which I'll just call `multifactor`) I leave as an exercise to you ;)

Third is the secret splitting. you can use an open source tool called "ssss" (google for "ssss-split") to split the luks password in the manner you describe. let's say you split it into 3 pieces (a,b,c) and require any 2 of them. store "a" on the usb drive, "b" in a vault, and "c" you store with the computer (unencrypted partition), or whatever. Of course you don't want "c" to be exposed, so encrypt it with a scheme of your choice using a passphrase you can remember, and call that passphrase "`c0`", and the encrypted "`c`" on your disk is "`c'`". Now your crypttab will look something like

```
root  /dev/disk/<blah blah>  /dev/<usb>:/path/to/a+$/dev/<blah>:/path/to/c'  keyscript=multifactor
```

*what you actually will have for the third field will of course depend on what your keyscript is willing to accept*

Ideally the keyscript should be able to determine that it needs your input to decrypt one or more of the keys (e.g.: `c'` -> `c` in this case), but you can use the third field to specify that as desired. In my example above, I used a leading `$` to indicate that.

I'm not sure if it's possible to make the keyscript prompt for input, possibly on stderr, since any output on stdout is taken as the luks password. It would be nice if there was a sensible fallback.

Anyway, good luck and happy hacking :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

You could have multiple keys in different slots , but that's not related to your question.

For security ， I maintain a checksum for ramdisks and cryptsetup is statically linked ， and I check them automatically everytime I boot.

**UPDATE**

The checksum is stored on encrypted FS , you can't modify it until you mount that partition.

That is , unless you're remotely exploited or your binary programs , e.g ramdisk / cryptsetup on rootfs is being modified, that's secure.
(BTW: My rootfs is encrypted , only kernel / ramdisk is naked there , that's why I check them only , but prepare for the slow loading speed with a slow CPU/HDD)

Comment: "I maintain a checksum for ramdisks ... and I check them automatically everytime I boot." What's to prevent someone from replacing the "expected" checksum value, if they have already gone to the trouble of stealing a thumb drive or making you (inadvertantly or not) reveal the passphrase?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling updated , please check

Comment: I don't see how that addresses what seems to be the OP's concern, namely in the face of involuntary disclosure of key material to an attacker. If you use a passphrase and they have installed a keylogger, they have your passphrase after the next reboot and will have no more trouble than you do using it to access the encrypted file system.

Answer (score 1):

With [LUKS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup#LUKS2) and [systemd v248](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v248/NEWS#L83-L97) (from March 2021) you can use [FIDO2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDO_Alliance#FIDO2) USB hardware security tokens for [multi-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) (MFA). You have to insert the security token device (something you have) and enter the device PIN (something you know) to unlock. While the PIN may be keylogged (like a passphrase), the security key cannot be copied (unlike a USB stick/keyfile) -- although it can be stolen (like a USB stick).

The device may have protection against PIN brute-force attacks while inserted/connected/stolen; resetting requires at the very least a different administrative PIN. Note that client PIN support is optional and model-specific; as are physical *user presence* and on-device *user verification* features.

Use [`systemd-cryptenroll`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptenroll.html) to configure the LUKS2 volume keyslots, in particular for the system disk or other always-connected disks listed in [`/etc/crypttab`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html). FIDO2 keys are [supposedly easy to use](https://0pointer.net/blog/unlocking-luks2-volumes-with-tpm2-fido2-pkcs11-security-hardware-on-systemd-248.html) for this purpose. There is also specific support for a high-entropy "recovery" passphrase, which may be helpful in case the security token is lost (or destroyed in a terrible stove-top accident), but apart from being used seldomly it suffers from the general passphrase drawbacks.

Note that [`cryptsetup`](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup) relies on the `systemd-fido2` token-type plugin, which manages additional FIDO2 keyslot metadata ([debugging example](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/784)). This plugin/library may not be available by default, in particular at boot time in `initramfs`; take care to create a (temporary, external) LUKS2 header backup and verify the setup before removing non-FIDO2 keyslots. See also [`/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup.html).

Bonus: since [systemd v246](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v246/NEWS#L416-L421) (from July 2020), [systemd-homed](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-homed.html) enables support for individual LUKS2 `$HOME` directories with FIDO2 security tokens (same or different from the system disk) with device PIN. Use [`homectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/homectl.html) to manage [JSON user records](https://systemd.io/USER_RECORD/) (different from classic UNIX users), [home directories/disks](https://systemd.io/HOME_DIRECTORY/), and their encryption keys. This is part of a larger [effort towards encryption, immutability, and portability](https://0pointer.net/blog/fitting-everything-together.html) etcetera. Among other things this allows storing and using the encrypted, portable `$HOME` directory directly from a (specifically) LUKS2-encrypted USB stick.